# Cannot Create Header On Website?

Tags: html, css

This might seem like a bad question, but I'm a bit of an HTML noob. Alright, so I'm trying to create an HTML topbar to my site. Here's the code I have:

CSS:

```
* html #top-bar {
  position: absolute;
}

#topbar-inner {
  height: 23px;
  background: #000000;
}

* html #topbar-inner {
  margin-right: 17px;
}
* html #topbar-right {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
width: 300px;
background-color: #b0e0e6;
}
```

HTML:

```css
#top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  color: white;
}

* html #top-bar {
  position: absolute;
}

#topbar-inner {
  height: 23px;
  background: #000000;
}

* html #topbar-inner {
  margin-right: 17px;
}
* html #topbar-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar"> 
  <center><font size="4"><div id="topbar-inner">FREE SHIPPING ON ALL ORDERS OVER $39!</div></font></center>
</div>
<br></br>
```

I'm trying to add text to the right of the screen while having the free shipping thing in the middle. Everytime I add  to my site, the text doesn't go next to it. What do I do to align it correctly?

THANKS

Comment: Hey Owen - try using the 'create code snippet' button in the question editor.  Make a live example.  It'll encourage people to answer.

Comment: Side note, the `<center>` and `<font>` tags were deprecated ages ago. Use CSS instead.

Comment: They still work though :/ @j08691

Comment: They work but @j08691 is right, use CSS.  What text are you trying to add to the right?

Comment: A log in and log out button. :/ @mtyson

Comment: I'd suggest not using ID's in CSS too, they're too specific. It's better to use classes, as they are reusable and you don't end up in a [specificity war](http://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/).

Comment: Could you show me what that CSS would look like? @AndiNorth

Comment: Can indeed. Give me a moment or two :)

Comment: Alright :D @AndiNorth

Comment: @OwenBick, I've added an answer with a link to a JSFiddle for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eoc5nq15/) that I believe solves your issue.

The text in the bar is center aligned and there is some text to the right, which is right aligned.

What's more, it's uses classes instead of ID's (as I mentioned in the comment above).

CSS is as follows (I'm also referencing normalise.css in the Fiddle to reset browser quirks).

```
.top-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 23px; /* Vertically align the text middle */
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center; /* Instead of <centre> */
    text-transform: uppercase; /* Capitalise the text in CSS */
}

.top-bar p {
    margin: 0;
}

.top-bar__right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: red; /* Just to make it stand out in this example */
    top: 0;
}
```

HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="top-bar">
    <p class="top-bar__middle">Free shipping on all orders over $39!</p>
    <p class="top-bar__right">This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I. LOVE. YOU. SO. MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
#top-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

#topbar-inner {
  height: 23px;
  background: blue;
  float:left;
   width:50%;
}

#topbar-inner {
 
  float:left;
}
#topbar-right {
position: relative;
float:right;
width: 300px;
background-color: #fff555;
 width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar"> 
<center>
  <div id="topbar-inner">FREE SHIPPING ON ALL ORDERS OVER $39!</div> 
  <div id="topbar-right">this is for the right topbar</div>   
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: No, text on the right and text in the middle. I'm having trouble making it do just that. @claudiu